# Semantic markup for language switcher

Tags: html, multilingual, semantic-markup

- Which markup would you use for a language switcher element?
- Should it be placed before `<header>` and `.skiplink`?
- Should it be prepended with heading?
- Any live examples?

Here is what I'm using now:

```
 <header>
        <div><a href="#content" class="skiplink">Skip to content</a></div>
        <h1>
            <a href="/">Site Name - the best site</a>                      
        </h1>
        </header>

                <ul class="langSwitch">
<li class="langPl"><img src="/gfx/pl.png" alt="Polski" /></li>
<li class="langEn"><a rel="nofollow" href="/en" hreflang="en" lang="en" xml:lang="en"><img src="/gfx/en.png" alt="English" /></a></li>
<li class="langDe"><a rel="nofollow" href="/de" hreflang="de" lang="de" xml:lang="de"><img src="/gfx/de.png" alt="Deutsch" /></a></li>
```

Comment: You can take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652346/html5-should-hreflang-always-point-to-a-direct-translation, I asked similar question, and this link may be usefull in the future.

Answer (score 13):

#### Content

As you already do, you should give the language names in the corresponding target languages, not in the current language.

As you use `img`, it’s likely that you are including national flags. You [shouldn’t do that](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/NOTE-i18n-html-tech-lang-20070412/#ri20040808.173208643). They symbolize countries, not languages.

If you like, you could use <s>the</s> a [Language Icon](http://www.languageicon.org/) (see also the [old version](http://www.languageicon.org/2008/index-icon.php)).

#### Placement

It should be placed near the top, so that text browser and screen reader browsers don’t have to fight through foreign language content to reach the language switcher, resp. to know that there are translations in the first place.

But I’d say it should be placed *after* the skiplink (especially if there are many translations), as the skiplink has exactly this job: skip over content that I don’t want to be repeated for every page.

#### Markup

Use the [`nav` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#the-nav-element). You could give it an explicit heading (this is more a usability question), but you don’t have to; if you don’t provide one, this sectioning element will be untitled in the outline.

This `nav` may, but doesn’t have to be, a child of the `body`-`header`.

Using `ul` inside of `nav` is appropriate.

Use [`rel`-`alternate` and `hreflang`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#rel-alternate) for the links, as it indicates that these are links to translations:

> If the alternate keyword is used with the hreflang attribute, and that attribute's value differs from the root element's language, it indicates that the referenced document is a translation.

Using `nofollow` is unusual for such links.

If you use HTML5 (not XHTML5), [you could omit the `xml:lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml%3alang-attributes) (it doesn’t have any effect in HTML5; it’s only to allowed to "ease migration").

#### Example

```
<nav>
  <h1>Translations of this page</h1> <!-- could be omitted → usability question -->
  <ul>
    <li>English</li> <!-- could be omitted → usability question -->
    <li><a rel="alternate" href="/pl" hreflang="pl" lang="pl">Polski</a></li>
    <li><a rel="alternate" href="/de" hreflang="de" lang="de">Deutsch</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: agree up to using anchor elements. they represent functionality, which button was created for.

Comment: @albert: Why’s that? Each translation is a separate document/page, so the `a` element is the obvious choice here. Also, if you would use `button` instead, you could not use the `hreflang` attribute (specifying the target language) and the `alternate` link type (specifying that it’s a translation, if used in combination with `hreflang` -- as [defined by the HTML5 (CR) spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#rel-alternate)).

Comment: ah. i didn't even look at href, i just assumed from "switcher" it was ajaxish...my bad.