# How to build a multilingual website and redirect user based on browser language?

Tags: jsp, redirect, web, search-engine

According to Google, it is important for multilingual website to have different urls for different languages.

For Example, it's better to have:
www.example.com      (for english in root folder)
www.example.com/cn/  (for chinese in cn folder)
www.example.com/fr/  (for french in fr folder)

This is good for search engine to crawl and thus SEO friendly.

However, google also suggests avoiding redirection:

> These redirections could prevent users (and search engines) from viewing all the versions of your site.

Then question comes, I want when people in China come to **example.com**, they see Chinese version, people in Franch coming to **example.com** see french version. Is there a way to do that while maintaining SEO friendly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I’m in China, I still want to be able to visit your English site. How would that be possible if your site is always showing me (resp. redirecting me to) the Chinese version?

When you’d use `example.com/en/` for the English site instead, you could redirect those people that visit `example.com/`. But only in that case! So, don’t change the language automatically when someone (no matter from where) is visiting a page in a specific language.

Use a [language switcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20157416/1591669) instead.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.xhaus.com/headers

Your browser sends to the website what it expects, Default to english if not sent,

```
  Accept-Language   en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

is mine for example, Prefer GB or US english but accept any english

Comment: Thanks, but how can we design the system to respond to the browser request? Google says redirection should be avoided.