# Having 2 Tumblr home pages

Tags: html, tumblr, posts

So I have a Tumblr blog (http://chatsonho.tumblr.com) that is written on my mother language (portuguese). I'm translating all of my pages and I wanted to have a duplicate posts page in english, is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean *pages* (as in custom pages) or posts (as in text/image/video posts)? You have "home pages" in the title of your question, but I assume that you don’t want to translate the front page only?

Comment: I mean the page where all the posts go. I wanted another posts page but with the layout in english. I've worked out a solution - I created another blog just to do that page in english:

http://chatsonhoing.tumblr.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tumblr doesn’t offer a way to translate your posts.

You can only provide interface strings (in custom themes) for supported languages.

### Workarounds

#### (1) Translation in the same post

You could include all languages in the same post, for example like:

```
 <article>
   <div lang="en"><!-- English here --></div>
   <div lang="de"><!-- German here --></div>
 </article>
```

You could even try implement a per-post language switcher in JavaScript.

Problems:

- doesn’t work well with non-text posts
- title can only be in one language

#### (2) Several posts in the same blog

You could create additional posts for each translation.

You might want to tag them ("English", "Deutsch", …).

Problems:

- readers would have to skip over all the translations (if they don’t use tags to browse)

#### (3) Several blogs

You could create additional blogs for each translation.

E.g., `example.tumblr.com` for English, `example-de.tumblr.com` for German, ….

---

### Language switcher

You might want to add a [language switcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20157416/1591669).

You could use the link type `alternate` in combination with the `hreflang` attribute to link to the translations of each post:

```
<a href="…" hreflang="de" rel="alternate" lang="de">Deutsch</a>
<a href="…" hreflang="en" rel="alternate" lang="en">English</a>
```